# Creating a route? Within a controller action_index? Kohana

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

I am working with kohana, because development goes so pretty fast. Now I want to achieve something which I can't really think of a workaround for.

What I want to achieve, there is a controller. It's called `Controller_Restaurants`
But those restaurants, are grouped by provinces and after province is clicked they are grouped by a city, and then a list of the restaurants is shown up.

All cities and provinces are already added to there specific database with fields.

I want to create a route in my controller. So can I achieve a following link:

```
domain/restaurants/province/city/restaurant-name
```

?

Or am I thinking like a douche and should I solve this otherwise?

Comment: Do what works if you want this to be done quickly. Also what's the exact question?

Comment: You can supply optional parameters in the route, please read [the manual](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#creating-routes). Possible route could be `restaurants(/<province>(/<city>(/<name>)))`

Comment: I tried to add a route myself, but it didn´t work, but apparently Ramon ´s piece of code works perfectly..  Well i guess i didn't watch close enough
Thanks anyway, i forgot that i had this question open. But i solved it with a filter action function for what i wanted to use this question for.. My apologies for the inconvience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your routing like this:

```
Route::set('restaurants', 'restaurants(/<province>(/<city>(/<name>))))',
    array(
        'controller' => 'restaurants',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

It should work like this.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to create routes inside a controller in Kohana, but it won't help you solve your problem because routing has already happened.

What you need to do is create a route with optional parameters as suggested by @kingkero:

```
restaurants(/<province>(/<city>(/<name>)))
```

Then access the parameters in the URL from the controller like so:

```
$province = $this->request->param('province');
...
```