# i need to get value in index controller without assign variable in url using kohana

Tags: url, routes, kohana

My url such as http://sandivartgallery.com//Tanjore-Paintings/Annapoorani . And I need retrieve value(Tanjore-Paintings and Annapoorani) in index controller . What should I do? (I'm working in Kohana)

Answer (score 0):

You define the parameters in your bootstrap, in the routes section.

`Route::set('default', '(/<foo>(/<bar>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'site',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));`

then you can get the paramaters using:
`$this->request->param('foo');` and `$this->request->param('bar');`

You can also take a look here: [Other awnser about routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282535/creating-a-route-within-a-controller-action-index-kohana/30321464#30321464)